# How to deploy a COM

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, deployment, com, registration

I just finished building my new COM project (C#, .NET 3.5). This project will be called by a VFP application. It's working great on my development machine, but now I need to know how to deploy it on the user's machine. Click Once isn't available for this kind of project, so I guess I'm stuck with manually distributing the DLL.

So, where should I put the DLL and how do I register it?

BTW, the 3.5 framework is already installed on the user's machine.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've really never used RegSvr32 with .Net assemblies, rather I use the regasm with the /codebase option:

```
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe /codebase mydll.dll
```

You can also use the /tlb option to export the type library and register it.

Of course the easiest way, just create an installer with vstudio and it will do this for you.

Comment: AN installer project, that is what I did for the COM I had to build for VFP.

Comment: I didn't know about the installer. I thought that ClickOnce was the only (free) way. Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 1):

**Creating a Description of the COM class and Interfaces**

.Net assemblies don't include information in Type Library compatible format. So it is necessary for the programmer to run one of two .Net-supplied utilities to extract the assembly description of a class into a Type Library file.

One utility is TLBEXP.EXE, the .Net Type Library Exporter. This command line utility takes as input the name of an assembly DLL file to be converted to a Type Library. The programmer can also specify the name of a Type Library file to be created.

```
tlbexp ComServer.dll /out:ComServer.tlb

Assembly exported to C:\Magellan\Source\Output\Debug\ComServer.tlb
```

Once a Type Library has been created, it can be referenced by a COM client to obtain the information necessary for the COM client to bind to the interfaces of the COM class, and activate the COM class at runtime.

**Registration of the COM Class and Interfaces**

For a COM class to be accessible by the client at runtime, the COM infrastructure must know how to locate the code that implements the COM class. The following command accomplishes this:

```
regasm ComServer.dll
```

Your DLL can be put anywhere you wish, but a good choice is C:\Program Files\MyApplication.

http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive190.html